# Finite Automata: Final vs Accepting States

Tags: automata, terminology, finite-automata

What is the difference between a final and accepting state when addressing an automaton?

As I understand it, a final state is depicted (traditionally) with a double circle, and apparently so is an accepting state. So if they are both depicted with the same symbol, what makes  a state particularly accepting?

Comment: I've a feeling this is a duplicate but I can't find it. Maybe I misremembered.

Answer (score 5):

Those are two words that mean exactly the same thing.